# how to tell the progress of a psql copy command using the heroku pg:psql terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, csv, heroku

I am uploading data from my local machine to a heroku database using the \copy command in the heroku pg:psql terminal. Is there a way to see what the progress is while a copy command is being executed? Currently I get no feedback until it is done.

I am anticipating this will annoy me once I am importing a few millions rows of data and it is taking a long time.

Comment: At the moment there's no progress indication for `\copy`. It'd be nice to have. Patches are welcome ;-)

Comment: Thanks Craig. I wish I knew how to do patches hehe. One day, one day...

Comment: If something does interrupt it or make it fail? i.e the internet drops out. Will it give feedback then or just hang?

Comment: Depends on your TCP timeout settings and the nature of the interruption. Client-side TCP keepalives will help ensure earlier detection of failure. Take a look at the PostgreSQL documentation on keepalives for server- and client- side. Unsure how much control you get over them with Heroku, though.